# How to run annotator in UIMA

Tags: java, opennlp, uima

I am using tutorial to run an opennlp annotator using UIMA by following [link](http://rimmythepaperclip.blogspot.in/2015/01/using-opennlp-with-apache-uima-project.html) and created the annotator using the link. As I run the annotator it gives me error of-

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
The method runAE(AnalysisEngine, String, String, JCas) in the type UimaUtils is not applicable for the arguments (AnalysisEngine, String, String)   NounPhraseTestor.java   /NounPhrase/src/org/apache/uima/tutorial    line 23 Java Problem

Infact i created the runAE in UimaUtils .Java still facing the error in runtime.

Comment: You can pass null as the last parameter, see here the source code: https://github.com/sujitpal/tgni/blob/93b87ec7fecf5f75559e4f2ac6efc9b9574cbd5f/src/main/java/com/mycompany/tgni/utils/UimaUtils.java#L82

Comment: i run it using 'null' in runAE in my junit testor it gave me error
    SEVERE: Exception occurred
  org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.AnalysisEngineProcessException: 
  Annotator processing failed.

Answer (score 0):

UIMA Annotators operates on CASes, if you want to process the string, add the string to doctext field of CAS and the do NLP on it.